# adding property while the bge is running?

Tags: python, game-engine

is it possible to add a game property to an object while the bge is running?

I realize you can access them easily enough, I am not asking about accessing properties just so that's clear.

I'm well aware that you can use a string as a list in the bge like so / which would be perfectly fine in most scenario's(and the same goes for dictionaries.) but I think it'd be more professional if you could physically add properties to objects in real time.

```
    import bge
    scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
    scene.objects['CentralControl']['L1']=str([(000.000,000.000,000.000),(000.000,000.000,000.001)])
print(scene.objects['CentralControl']['L1'])
```

*postscript: this probably isn't important but i'm using blender v2.78a*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's possible.

Game objects behave like dictionaries, so you can just assign any value to any name (no need for adding a property in the Blender GUI):

```
scene.some_object["new_property"] = "Hello"
```

You can even store lists, objects and any other data type in these properties.

Comment: this is considerably easier than I thought it was going to be >.>. and i've used bge for quite a long time now lmao